# Passing a function to Child Component through a Prop using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I have a class  that contains the  class Component.

When I provide an onClick prop for the  to use and try to pass a function, I get the following error:

AddForm.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: _this3.props.onClick is not a function

Code:

```js
export default class Company extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
  AddOrView: <AddForm header="Add User" formFields={this.fields} />,
  users: this.props.initialUsers
 }
  }
  handleAdd() {
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
       <AddWithTitle onClick={e => this.setState({ 
         AddOrView: <AddForm header="Add User" 
                                    formFields={this.fields} 
        formResponses="" 
        onClick={this.handleAdd} /> 
             })
        } src="blah.png">
     Add User</AddWithTitle>
    );
  }
}

export default class AddForm extends React.Component {
   
  render() {
      return(
          <button className="btn btn-primary" 
    formResponses={this.state.fieldValues} 
    onClick={() => this.props.onClick()} >
    Save
    </button>
      );
   }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why do you have two `Company` classes. You can't create props in one definition of a class and then hope when you try to redefine it the props appear. Just combine those two render functions into the top definition and use the click handler definition itself instead of the prop

Comment: Sorry mistype on the class, just edited, it is supposed to be AddForm. Not the source of the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using set state in your render return function, but leaving that aside all you're doing is adding the <AddForm> jsx to your state in the `Company` return function... you never actually render the `<AddForm />` And have you defined `<AddWithTitle />` somehwhere?

Comment: Yes I have, I didn't want to throw a lot of the code in that I know is not the source of the issue. Later in the code I use: {this.state.AddOrView} which summons either an add or view module. It's just supposed to differentiate between add and view. I do define AddWith Title @Chase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the function to your top level component for it to fire whatever you want it to fire in the `onClick` method.

```
   <AddWithTitle onClick={e => this.setState({ 
        AddOrView: <AddForm header="Add User" 
                                formFields={this.fields} 
                formResponses="" 
                onClick={this.handleAdd.bind(this)} /> 
                        })
             } src="blah.png">
    Add User</AddWithTitle>
```

Comment: Sweet so that eliminated the error, but now it is still not doing the console.log('Hello World'), thoughts?

Comment: weird. did you try to refresh the page and try again? Also, like the above poster mentioned, don't set state in your render function. It's an anti pattern and it's going to cause errors. Create separate methods for each click event, it's cleaner that way and it's going to prevent errors from occurring in the future.

Comment: Okay, I will make that change, thank you, and yes I tried refreshing and what not. I believe it may have something to do with it being in the setState. @Mabeh Al-Zuq Yadeek

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't work inside the render method. Surprised you didn't receive an error.

Comment: Mabeh Just an update: I got it to work. There were a couple of things wrong. I was unaware that you had to put in your constructor `this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this)`. WOW, and second, in my constructor I did not put the `onClick` function, so the first component rendered did not have the `onClick` functionality. Oh boy. But you definitely led me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You have to bind the method to the specific component that it's located in. If you don't bind it, it won't know the exact reference of the method and it will throw an error, just like any other JavaScript constructor. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I don't understand why you tried to render the DOM within setState. Really wierd, tacky and spaghetti, isn't it ? Why not use a bool for AddNotView = true, this.setState({ AddNotView = !this.setState.AddNotView}) ? Then inside your render method, write your ternary check for rendering down there. Readability suffers greatly dueto wierd setState.  and put your handler in the constructor as you did.